# Article author in blog does not display

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to show the *article author* on my PHP website. It doesn't give any errors, but it isn't showing the name either.

This is my function:

```
public static function userName(){
$db = self::getDBConnection();
    $articles = Article::getAll();
    foreach ($articles as $key => $article)
    {
        $user = new User($article['user_id']);
        $articles[$key]['username'] = $user->name;

    }
}
```

This is what I use to call function:

```
<li class="author">by <?php echo   Article::userName() ;?></a></li>
```

Comment: Sorry, this question appears to be truncated, the code is not properly formatted and in general it is unclear what you ask, since we do not know the implementation of those classes and methods you appear to be using. Please invest time into improving your question. There is an `edit` button below it. _Use it_.

Comment: `userName()` doesn't return anything that I can see, so you might get the name but you don't `return` it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not return anything. Try returning eg: the list of user like below:

```
public static function userName(){
  $db = self::getDBConnection();
  $articles = Article::getAll();
  foreach ($articles as $key => $article)
  {
      $user = new User($article['user_id']);
      $articles[$key]['username'] = $user->name;
      $myListOfUser .=   $articles[$key]['username']  . ' - ';
  }
  return $myListOfUser;
}
```